# Aligning HTML elements over canvas

Tags: html, canvas, doctype, quirks-mode

I am having touble figuring out why a program is failing.  I am writing a code generator that generates canvas, but my expertice is in regular compiled languages, not javascript, canvas, nor web.

I was prototyping some code in Dreamweaver and happened to have accidentally put an askerisk immediately before the first line.  As I understand it, the askerisk made the header invalid and that allows the browser to run in quirks mode.

When I discovered the invalid header, I removed the askerisk and my working application started failing.  I kept simplifying the code and pulling out things trying to find what was invalid code and I am down to less than 30 lines, can't find it and there is very little more I can pull out and still leave the basic operation being done - placing a SELECT list over a canvas.

When this code is run in most browsers, it works until you remove the askerisk at the very top of the file.  When it fails, the text "Align me" appears in the middle of the page and the SELECT OPTION combo box is placed at the page origin.  Can someone tell me what is wrong with code?

```
*<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <form id='h1'; style='position:relative'>
    <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1">
      <canvas id="c1" width="310" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
      </canvas>
    </div>

     <select id='s1' style='position:absolute; z-index:2'>
        <option value='Please select'>Please select</option>
     </select>
  </form> 
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var can=document.getElementById("c1");
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");   
    ctx.font = 'bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';;
    ctx.textAlign='right';
    ctx.fillStyle ='#CCC';      
    ctx.fillText("Align Me", 130, 160);

    var ele = document.getElementById('s1');
    ele.style.top = 140;
    ele.style.left= 140;
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put a up a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: When you say "over" a canvas - where over the canvas? Top left?

Comment: I put a jsfiddle of the solution at http://jsfiddle.net/vfanberg/KCZ5g/ - it turned out I just needed to add "px" to the javacode.

Comment: What I meant by "over a canvas" is that the element was precisely placed at any specific place above the canvas.  In this case, the output has text written in the center of canvas and an html listbox positioned right after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a wrapper div around your form and canvas elements.

Take the canvas out of your form element!

Then make the wrapper-div position:relative and both the form & canvas position:absolute

Result...Your select element is aligned where you want it!

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/5UzhE/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
#wrapper{position:relative;}
#d1{position:absolute top:0; left:0; z-index:1; }
#c1{width:310px; height:300px; border:1px solid #d3d3d3;}
#h1{position:absolute; top:140px; left:140px; z-index:2; }
</style>
<head>
  <div id="wrapper" style='position:relative'>

    <form id='h1';>
      <select id='s1' style='position:absolute; z-index:2'>
          <option value='Please select'>Please select</option>
      </select>
    </form> 

    <div id='d1'>
      <canvas id="c1" width="310" height="300">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
      </canvas>
    </div>

  </div>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var can=document.getElementById("c1");
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");   
    ctx.font = 'bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';;
    ctx.textAlign='right';
    ctx.fillStyle ='#CCC';      
    ctx.fillText("Align Me", 130, 160);
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave markE credit for answering this.  He had a lot of good suggestions and pointed me to the answer.  After studying his solution, it turned out all I really needed was the proper format for javascript setting the position.  I had  "ele.style.top = 140;" and what I should have had was "ele.style.top = '140px';".  So, here is a solution with minimal changes (this will become computer generated code, not something that will be maintained by hand, so I am not as concerned with changes such as pulling out style sheets). Here is a fiddle of the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/vfanberg/KCZ5g/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <form id='h1'; style='position:relative'>
    <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1">
      <canvas id="c1" width="310" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
      </canvas>
    </div>

     <select id='s1' style='position:absolute; z-index:2'>
        <option value='Please select'>Please select</option>
     </select>
  </form> 
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var can=document.getElementById("c1");
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");   
    ctx.font = 'bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';;
    ctx.textAlign='right';
    ctx.fillStyle ='#CCC';      
    ctx.fillText("Align Me", 130, 160);

    var ele = document.getElementById('s1');
    ele.style.top = '140px';
    ele.style.left= '140px';
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```